# C++ Better hash function for store strings

Tags: c++, string, hash

I have been trying to find hash function rather than quadratic probing if it has a fastest way.
word is for string that i want to store and count is word frequency where i found at txt file. And string must be lowercase. So my question is there a hash function faster than quadratic probing for this problem without using third-party libraries?

```
struct wordCount {
    std::string word;
    int count;
};

void insert(std::string& word, const int count_){
    int hashIndex = 0;
    int probingIteration = 0;


    for (int i= 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'){

            word[i] = word[i] + ('a' - 'A');
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i= 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        hashIndex += word[i]; // ascii values sum
    }

    while(probingIteration < size) {
        if (table[(hashIndex + (probingIteration * probingIteration)) % size].word == word) {
            table[(hashIndex + (probingIteration * probingIteration)) % size].count += count_;
            length++;

            return;
        } else {
            if (table[(hashIndex + (probingIteration * probingIteration)) % size].count == -1) {
                table[(hashIndex + (probingIteration * probingIteration)) % size].word = word;
                table[(hashIndex + (probingIteration * probingIteration)) % size].count = count_;
                length++;
                return;
            } else {
                probingIteration++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash

Comment: I would try better hash rather than trivial sum, for example CRC is fast and should have much better collision rate. Btw is it not obvious that you do exactly the same loop twice?

Comment: Don’t hand-roll character classification and conversions. ’std::tolower` will do the job in that first loop.

Comment: and the better hash algorithm depends on the type of string, for example hashing an ASCII string containing English texts without special characters is obviously different from hashing a string in Japanese in Shift-JIS or Arabic in UTF-8